# Missing formal parameter in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

I need to parse multiple email bodies using google apps script, that look like:

```
Name: Bob smith
Email: hellol@aol.com
Phone Number: 4243331212
```

To do this, I am trying to turn the following:

```
body.split('\n').forEach(v=>v.replace(/\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*/, 
(s,key,val)=>{obj[key]=isNaN(val)||val.length<1?val||undefined:Number(val);}));
```

into a function that appscript can run by changing arrow functions to returned functions like:

```
function parseBody (body) {
var obj = {}; 

 body.split("\n").forEach(function(v) { 

   return v.replace(/\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*/, function((s,key,val){ 
  return {obj[key]=isNaN(val)||val.length<1?val||undefined:Number(val)};
})
})
```

However when I run this in the script editor I see "missing formal parameters" . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a following modified script?

#### Script :

```
function parseBody(body) {
  body = "Name: Bob smith\nEmail: hellol@aol.com\nPhone Number: 4243331212\n"; // As a sample

  var obj = {};
  body.split("\n").forEach(function(v) {
    return v.replace(/\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*/,
      function(s,key,val) {
        return obj[key] = isNaN(val) || val.length < 1 ? val || undefined : Number(val);
      }
    )
  });
  Logger.log(obj)
}
```

#### Result :

```
{
  "Name": "Bob smith",
  "Email": "hellol@aol.com",
  "Phone Number": 4243331212
}
```

Comment: Thanks man , it works! Let me ask you, what does the 's' in function(s,key,val) refer to ?

Comment: @user61629 Welcome. Thank you, too. The first parameter ``s`` of function means all values retrieved by the regular expression. For example, in your case, ``s``, ``key`` and ``val`` are ``Name: Bob smith. ``, ``Name`` and ``Bob smith``, respectively.